# Storing percolator in separate index when only one mapping is possible per index?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-percolate

I have a `SearchAgent` document in an index called `searchagent` which looks like this:

```
[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "Id")]
public class SearchAgent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Keyword]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public QueryContainer Query { get; set; }
}
```

This is because I want my users to create "search agents" that will notify the user when a new document for a specific search has been inserted.

Now, the document that I want to find the relevant search agent for, is in the `items` index and is an `Item`. It looks like the following:

```
[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "Id")]
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

This also seems to be what [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) recommends:

> Given the design of percolation, it often makes sense to use separate indices for the percolate queries and documents being percolated, as opposed to a single index ...

However, I can't index my search agent documents now, since their `Query` refers to a property on the `Item` document. And this leads to the following error:

> No field mapping can be found for the field with name [title]

I guess this means that I both have to describe the `Item` *and* `SearchAgent` mapping in the `searchagent` index.

But in Elasticsearch 6, they [removed support for multiple mappings per index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html), so this is not possible.

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess this means that I both have to describe the `Item` and `SearchAgent` mapping in the `searchagent` index.

This is correct for 6.x. Essentially, percolation needs to know about the mapping of the documents that will be percolated, so the index that contains the queries also needs to have the fields for the documents that will be percolated.

With NEST 6.x, it's possible to do this with

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("percolation", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<SearchAgent>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap<SearchAgent>()
            .AutoMap<Item>()
        )
    )
);
```

This will automap the properties of both `SearchAgent` and `Item` under the mapping for `SearchAgent` and will result in the following request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/percolation?pretty=true 
{
  "mappings": {
    "searchagent": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "query": {
          "type": "percolator"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE** that a property with the same name on both POCOs will take the mapping of the last property of that name to be mapped, so it's recommended that the properties have the same mapping or better yet, that the query documents contain differently named properties (`Id` is fine if they're both mapped the same), to avoid potential confusion down the track.

With the percolation index set up, targeting documents in another index would now be achieved with

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<SearchAgent>(s => s
    .Index("percolation") // index containing queries
    .Query(q => q
        .Percolate(p => p
            .Type<Item>() 
            .Index("items") // index containing documents
            .Id("item-id") // document id
            .Field(f => f.Query) // field on SearchAgent containing query
        )        
    )
);
```

which executes the following query

```
POST http://localhost:9200/percolation/searchagent/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "id": "item-id",
      "index": "items",
      "type": "item"
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to also set up conventions for the POCOs on `ConnectionSettings`

```
var defaultIndex = "default-index";
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
    .DefaultMappingFor<SearchAgent>(d => d
        .IndexName("percolation")
    )
    .DefaultMappingFor<Item>(d => d
        .IndexName("items")
    );

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Then the search request can use

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<SearchAgent>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Percolate(p => p
            .Type<Item>()
            .Index<Item>()
            .Id("item-id")
            .Field(f => f.Query)
        )        
    )
);
```

Finally, take a look at the [NEST Percolation Query DSL documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/percolate-query-usage.html); it could definitely do with improvement as it omits some information that is not included when it is autogenerated from the test suite, but hopefully it gives you an idea. With any NEST documentation, you can always click the edit button on the docs page to get a link to the original source from which it is generated:

[image: Edit docs link]

and

[image: Original source code]

which leads to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/6.x/src/Tests/Tests/QueryDsl/Specialized/Percolate/PercolateQueryUsageTests.cs in the case of the Percolate 6.x documentation.

Comment: The automapping part doesn't work. When only the mapping from `SearchAgent` is in the percolation index when I check it out. Do you have any idea of why this may be the case? Is inheritance of the classes needed?